# Put a dynamic array on a variable

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

This is my static array, i've been using this one to show the line on google maps.

```
$polyline = array();
        $polyline['points'] = array('-6.343, 106.814',
                '-6.343, 106.8143',
                '-6.34567, 106.8140');
        $marker['infowindow_content'] = 'Mobil 1!';
        $marker['icon'] = 'http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=A|9999FF|000000';
        $this->googlemaps->add_polyline($polyline);

        $data['map'] = $this->googlemaps->create_map();
```

I want to get a dynamic data from JSON and put on those below array.

```
$polyline['points'] = array('-6.343, 106.814',
                '-6.343, 106.8143',
                '-6.34567, 106.8140');
```

I've been try to create below function.

```
public function testGetMap() {
    $this->load->model('modelMap');

    $getMap = $this->modelMap->getMap();

    $encoded = json_encode($getMap, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);

    $decoded = json_decode($encoded,TRUE);

        $a = array();
        foreach($decoded as $item) { 
             array_push($a, $item['latitude'].','.$item['longitude']);
        }


    var_dump($polyline['points']);
}
```

and called this on that particular function.

```
$polyline['points'] = $this->testGetMap();
```

But it is not working at all. please help on this.

Comment: Use `return $a` inside `testGetMap` to return your array!!

Comment: hi @Saty thanks its works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Juste replace your

```
var_dump($polyline['points']);
```

With

```
return $a;
```

Answer (score -1):

Array `$a` should be returned inside the function definition area. This is not here. Thats why it isn't reflecting.